# Distorted text graphics with JAR NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, pong

I'm doing the Pong game with text graphics and i've a problem when i create jar file.

When I execute the game inside NetBeans all is perfect, but when I create the jar file and execute it, all graphics are distorted and misplaced.

Someone can help me??

Comment: What are you using to display your graphics? By "text graphics" you mean some form of ASCII art you are printing in your console? Can you show us some snippet of how you are displaying such "graphics" and describe how you are seeing them outside netbeans? (it might be an encoding issue)

Comment: I'm using a matrix of characters where ball and rackets are represented with '\u2588' character, so for display this graphics I only call 'toString' method. This method loop into matrix and concatenate each char in a string, which will be return at the end.

Comment: Maybe it's related to the font in your console (I don't know where you executed that from) but probably the command line font does not include a valid character for \u2588. Try changing your command line font

Comment: Yes!! It was the font I was using, I had 'Lucida Sans typewriter' and this font don't support block elements from unicode. When I changed it for 'Curier New' the problem was solved. 
Thanks for all!